# cvLoadImage under roslaunch

Tags: ros, opencv, roslaunch, path, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, reading this post:

http://answers.ros.org/question/31491/cvloadimage-fail-in-ros/?comment=45908#comment-45908

I have the same problem. This is my code:

```
  IplImage *img = NULL;

  img = cvLoadImage("$(find lsi_node)/images/herramientas.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  cvNamedWindow("result",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  cvShowImage("result", img);
  cvWaitKey(0);
```

where lsi_node is the real package, images is the folder inside this package which contains the images and herramientas.jpg is the picture which I want to load.

This image doesn't load. The includes are:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "sensor_msgs/Image.h"
#include "image_transport/image_transport.h"
#include "cv_bridge/CvBridge.h"
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

I miss some command or something like ' or ` or " or in the path of my image? or any include?

In the roslaunch:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="lsi_node" type="lsi_node" name="lsi_node" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

**SOLVED**

Finally I find the solution of this topic.

This is the final code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "sensor_msgs/Image.h"
#include "image_transport/image_transport.h"
#include "cv_bridge/CvBridge.h"
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <ros/package.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "lsi_node");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  std::string path = ros::package::getPath("lsi_node");
     
  IplImage *img = NULL;

  path.append("/images/herramientas.jpg");

  img = cvLoadImage(path.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  cvNamedWindow("result",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  cvShowImage("result", img);
  cvWaitKey(0);
  cvDestroyWindow("result");
}
```

And actually the picture appear in the screen.

Hope this will be useful.

Best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45909/cvloadimage-under-roslaunch/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does image load if you dont use $(find lsi_node) ?

Try loading:

```
img = cvLoadImage("herramientas.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

and put *herramientas.jpg* into *~/.ros* directory. If it works you can change working directory to *$(find lsi_node)* for this node with your launch file.

$(find lsi_node) in code code may not work as wanted, bacause it is not a launch file. You could try to work with:

```
 `rospack find lsi_node`
```

---

Originally posted by [kszonek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2959/kszonek/) with karma: 459 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-15**:
If you want to use package relative filenames in ros nodes, the best way is to use [resource_retriver](http://ros.org/wiki/resource_retriever).